# Network share file access debugging with OS hardening

Tags: c#, networking

is there a way in C# to see what credentials are used to access a file in a network share?

I'm trying to debug a scenario where most of CIS Windows L1 hardening settings are applied to a system. This system only has local users and one of them (a member of local Administrators group) is used to run a C# app (.NET Framework 4.7.2) that accesses a network share, say `\\myserver\some\path\foo.xml`. Without hardening, it all works fine, even though when I have a look at who can access the network share, the local user is not listed.

With hardening applied, it does not work. More concretely: in File Explorer, when trying to access the `foo.xml`, a CredUI prompt for credentials appears. I have to submit my own credentials (AD user) to get access.

What the app does is essentially

```cs
string[] possiblePaths = ... // load possible network paths of desired file

foreach (string possiblePath in possiblePaths)
{
    if (File.Exists(possiblePath))
    {
        return possiblePath;
    }
}
```

I figured out how to deal with the `SeTcbPrivilege` policy violation (that gave me errors in the Event Log), but after that, I am lost.

To debug, I have created a test app:

```cs
string path = @"\\myserver\some\path\foo.xml";

if (File.Exists(path))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Path {path} exists!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Path {path} does not exist!");
}

try
{
    var fh = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
    fh.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    if (ex.InnerException != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```

When I restart the system and try to run the app without providing my credentials to File Explorer, it says "The path does not exist" and IOException that the network path does not exist. However, when I submit my own credentials (not the local user, but mine, as an AD user) in File Explorer to access that location, the output of the test app says "The path exists" and UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path ... is denied. Which is weird, as I don't run the app as me, but as the local user.

I know I can use trial-error (and probably will) to identify the policy messing it up, but I would like to constrain it as much as possible - and also to understand *why exactly* it is causing trouble (maybe there used to be some anonymous/guest access on the share that is not permitted now on the system?).

To that extent, I would very welcome any nudge as how to see what credentials a C# app is using to authenticate elsewhere, how to get more debug info, or how the `File.Exists()`/`File.Open()` work under the hood.

Thanks!

Comment: By default it uses what the owner of the process is using

Comment: `WNetGetUser`, you'll probably have to use p/invoke because I'm not aware of any wrapper in .NET BCL

Comment: @DanielA.White yep, but all runs under the local Admin account. Once it says 'path does not exist', when I use my own domain account credentials to access it in File Explorer, File.Exists() says 'path exists', but File.Open() throws 'permission denied' instead of IOException. Almost as if Windows used cache and initially did not know such network path, but after I provide my credentials elsewhere to access it, Win already knows it - but then the permissions fail. :(